# Why [machine_name].local works when remote login is enabled?

Tags: ssh, 18.04, remote-access

I noticed that my 18.04 has "Remote Login" (Settings => Sharing) setting. When it's enabled you can SSH to the machine (`ssh [machine_name].local`). How does this work? How do the other machines magically know who is `[machine_name].local` ?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question because remote access to a systwm has numerous implementations and methods (SSH, VNC, RDP, Telnet which is ancient, etc.). You will need to be more specific in what you mean by remote access and where this setting sits that you are seeing.

Comment: Ok, what I meant was how the other machines know the IP of the machine by this naming convention. I edited the question.

Comment: A combination of Avahi, mDNS on a local scope, and DNS.  In this case, Avahi and its mDNS queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the Avahi service, which uses the `.local` domain as a multicast DNS zone.

See `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` There will be a `domain-name=.local` under the "server" section where you can change it. `.local` is the default if you did not change it.

Comment: Hmm...actually there is now: `#domain-name=local` ...is there another config file somewhere?

Comment: @user205301 in man page of avahi-daemon.conf, it says `domain-name= Set the default domain name avahi-daemon tries to register its host name and services on the LAN in. If omitted defaults to ".local"`.

Comment: @user205301 oh sorry  ".local" is the default. Change it to "somethingelse", restart the service and you'd be using "ubuntu.somethingelse" ;)